# Trying to install jeykll on my mac I ran into this error?

Tags: ruby, terminal, permissions, rubygems, jekyll

So, Im trying to install Jeykll on my mac as I said upon running gem I got this error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

Im not a terminal whiz by any means so I was following a tutorial when I got this. Im wondering if there is an easy fix for this so I can actually install Jekyll on my Mac.
im on a Mac pro Sonoma 14 and would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a permission error, it is some piece of software (in this particular case the OS) telling you that you are trying to do something you are not allowed to do.

The first, and most important, thing you need to do now is to *investigate why that is the case*. Do not try to find any workarounds, backdoors, tricks, etc. If you do not understand why you get the error, you can seriously break your system by trying to work around the error.

There are, essentially two possibilities:

1. The error is correct: you shouldn't be doing what you are trying to do in the first place. In other words: the restriction is correct, what you are doing is wrong.
2. The error is wrong: you *should* be allowed to do what you are trying to do, but somehow the permissions are set up incorrectly. In other words: the restriction is *incorrect*.

Blindly using a tool like [`su`](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)), [`sudo`](https://sudo.ws/), or [`doas`](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Doas) in a unixoid OS, or [`runas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) or [UAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/) in Windows in order to simply disable the security barrier is the *wrong thing to do* in both cases.

In case #1, the correct thing to do is *nothing*. You are doing something you shouldn't be doing. You need to find a different approach.

In case #2, the correct thing to do is to ask your system administrator to fix the wrong permissions so that you get access to the resource you should have access to.

In other words: in case #1, the barrier is there for a reason and in case #2, the barrier shouldn't be there in the first place. Jumping over it is the wrong thing in both cases.

Now, there *are* legitimate reasons *for a system administrator* to use `sudo` in order to make *fundamental changes to the base configuration of the OS*. But this is not such a situation.

Unfortunately, it has become all too common that users are conditioned to simply fix any issue by retrying the operation with `sudo` without even thinking about why the issue even occurred in the first place. [This answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77378435/2988) demonstrates the problem: the answerer tells you to use `sudo` without explaining what it is doing and why you need it, but more importantly, without even mentioning that what you are doing is wrong in the first place. This is highly dangerous. If you are one of those people suffering from "sudo-itis", I encourage you to hang out on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and observe the questions by distraught users who have lost invaluable data by blindly using `sudo` without understanding what they are doing.

Ask yourself: is installing a blogging platform something that should require you to involve a system administrator and make fundamental changes to the OS? I assume, you find this idea as strange as I do, so something must clearly be wrong here.

The answer is:

You are trying to overwrite parts of the system Ruby installation. [*Do not do that*](https://moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby-to-install-gems-on-a-mac/). The system Ruby installation, provided by Apple, is for *use by the system itself* and for "legacy software". [It is *not* to be used by the user](https://dontusesystemruby.com/).

See [this official statement by Apple as part of the release notes for macOS Catalina](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes#Scripting-Language-Runtimes):

> Scripting language runtimes such as Python, Ruby, and Perl are included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. Future versions of macOS won’t include scripting language runtimes by default, and might require you to install additional packages. If your software depends on scripting languages, it’s recommended that you bundle the runtime within the app.

Even worse, a RubyGem can run arbitrary code during its installation process. If you install a RubyGem using `sudo`, [you allow that Gem to run arbitrary code on your computer with full administrative privileges](https://moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/).

So, what is the correct thing to do?

The correct thing to do is to install your own Ruby into a directory that you have access to and use that installation instead of the system one.

There are many different ways to do this. Personally, I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as a package manager. But I don't use the [ruby formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ruby) directly, instead, I use the [rbenv formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rbenv) to install [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage my Ruby installations and the [ruby-install formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ruby-install) to install [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) for installing Ruby implementations.

Then, I can just use `rbenv install` to install a particular version of a particular Ruby implementation, `rbenv global` to set the version I want to use by default and `gem install` to install RubyGems for this particular version.

Answer (score -1):

you seem to be using osx default ruby version, so to install a gem you need to prefix the command with *sudo* (super user do) because ruby is installed in a path where your normal user you're logged in as does not have write access:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```